# Angular ng-show callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the height of an element which will appear when mouse over of a button.

Example code:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="mouseoverPopUp()" ng-mouseleave="showpop=false">menu</div>
<div class="popover" ng-show="showpop">{{content}}</div>

$scope.mouseoverPopUp = function($event){
    $scope.showpop = true;
    var height = angular.element(".popover").innerHeight();
};
```

The problem is sometimes the height of the element is being get before it is appeared. Is there anyway I can run the code only have the `ng-show` has show the element? I need to get the height ASAP after it appear to adjust the position of the element.

Comment: Only a guess did you try watching showpop instead of listening for mouseover ?

Comment: @BorisCharpentier How can I do watching on showpop? Is that mean when the variable is change, the element will already appear?

Comment: I will suggest you make a directive for this..

Comment: @Ved Yeah, I will make it into directive. Are you suggesting that making into directive will solve the problem?

Comment: yes.. it will solve. Bind element on event you want.. for example, element.on('mouseover', function () {your code})

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with your code inside a $timeout call in order to delay the execution of your JS after angular finished working ?

```
$scope.mouseover = function($event){
    $timeout(function() {
        var height = angular.element(".popover").innerHeight();
    });
};
```

How are you showing your popover? with a css transition ? If so you'll need to delay accordingly your JS code retrieving the height. Or you can use angular-animate to bind events with more logic

ps: to help more, a jsfiddle would be great

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't prefer the `timeout` way to delay the code execution. It would be nice if you could show an example how to do the callback with angular-animate.